# What format of date/time object does moment js accept?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

`moment("2019-08-22T09:00:00")` successfully creates a Moment object, but if I try to do `moment("9:00")` it doesn't. If I've provided only the hour like that, I have to do `moment("9:00", "h:mm")`.

**My Question Is:**

What format(s) of date/time string do I have to pass to `moment()` in order to not have to specify the format, as I did with `moment("9:00", "h:mm")`?

Comment: The first one is a valid [ISO 8601 string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can see on [the moment's document](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), there are three categories of tokens can be used in the format:

- Week year, week, and weekday tokens
- Locale aware formats
- Hour, minute, second, millisecond, and offset tokens

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string
> matches known [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601%5D) formats, we then check if the string matches
> the [RFC 2822 Date time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) format before dropping to the fall back of new
> Date(string) if a known format is not found.

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass a second argument to moment() using a `.format()` method

Try this:

```
moment("2019-08-22T09:00:00").format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.